# libglib2.0-0 accidentally deleted

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I accidentally type this `dpkg --force-all --remove libglib2.0-0` in Ubuntu command line and suddenly I get this massage whenever I try to install a software:

```
telepathy-gabble : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
telepathy-haze : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
telepathy-idle : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
telepathy-indicator : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.25.9) but it is not going to be installed
telepathy-logger : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.25.11) but it is not going to be installed
telepathy-mission-control-5 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
telepathy-salut : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
thunderbird : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
totem : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
totem-mozilla : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.27.92) but it is not going to be installed
totem-plugins : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.27.92) but it is not going to be installed
transmission-gtk : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: fonts-freefont-ttf but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-calculator but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gstreamer1.0-alsa but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpam-systemd but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: memtest86+ but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-drivers-common but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-settings but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-sso-client-qt but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: cheese but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: fonts-lklug-sinhala but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: fonts-sil-abyssinica but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: fonts-sil-padauk but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: fonts-tibetan-machine but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-mahjongg but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: im-config but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-pdfimport but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-presentation-minimizer but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
ubuntuone-client-gnome : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.26.0) but it is not going to be installed
udev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not going to be installed
udisks : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity-2d-panel : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity-2d-shell : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity-greeter : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
unity-lens-applications : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity-lens-files : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity-lens-music : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
unity-scope-musicstores : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity-services : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
update-notifier : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
upower : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
vino : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
whoopsie : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
xdg-user-dirs-gtk : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
xul-ext-ubufox : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.26) but it is not going to be installed
yelp : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
zeitgeist-core : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
zeitgeist-datahub : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.26.0) but it is not going to be installed
zenity : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0 && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of the text, which means "I accept the answer"

Comment: the correcting dependencies too long and then connection of my vps got disconnect